# Python: How to divide row values in csv file with respect to assigned specific values?

Tags: python, csv, operators, division, elementwise-operations

I would like do perform division with respect to its alphabet. Given an example as below:

The binary file given is in csv format:

```
A=1000, C=0100, G=0010, T=0001
```

**binary.csv: CAT, GAA**

```
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

The binary.csv need to multiply with a single line values which is in csv file.

**single.csv:**

```
0.28,0.22,0.23,0.27,0.12,0.29,0.34,0.21,0.44,0.56,0.51,0.65
```

The code below do multiplication for values in both files and output:

```
0.22,0.12,0.65
0.23,0.12,0.44
```

**Code**

```
import csv

with open('single.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        reals = row

with open('binary.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    pwreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    with open('output.csv','wb') as testfile:
        csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
        for row in pwreader:
            result = []            
            for i,b in enumerate(row):
                if b == '1' :
                    result.append(reals[i])
            csv_writer.writerow(result)
```

I have additional csv file that I would like to perform division for previous
            output and the values that are divided with respect to its alphabet:

```
 A   C   G   T
 0.4,0.5,0.7,0.1
 0.2,0.8,0.9,0.3
```

the value for CAT is divided by 0.5,0.4,0.1 and GAA is divided by 0.9,0.2,0.2 respectively so that I can get a whole new output as follows:

```
 0.44,0.3,6.5
 0.26,0.6,2.2
```

using numpy on array can possibly solve this but when used on more than couple of thousands data it might not be suitable. Out of memory was occurred when I tried on 60,000++ data.

Can anyone help me?